# Angular.JS apply template with tags

Tags: javascript, templates, angularjs

I have `AngularJS` web application and `<p>` in it. I want to apply template to the `<p>`, to the `innerHTML`. My template in file which in the server. Template is simple text with some tags like `<b>`, `<ol>` and and etc... text tags.

For example my template:

```
Lorem <b>ipsum</b> dolor <i>sit</i> amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
```

I load this content via ajax from the server and try to apply this template to `<p>` inner html:

```
<p>{{template}}<p>
```

And in my controller:

```
// load here template
...
// apply template
$scope.template = template;
```

But i see text with tags, i see:

```
Lorem <b>ipsum</b> dolor <i>sit</i> amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
```

in browser with all tags. I want see formated text without tags. How can i make it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize.directive:ngBindHtml or http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngBindHtmlUnsafe

```
<p ng-bind-html="template"></p>
```